# How to count specific word in Google Sheets without matching parts of words

Tags: google-sheets

I am trying to count the occurrences of the word "desk" in the text of A1 cell for example. All the text is in lowercase, it contains "desk" many times, the word sometimes has punctuation marks at the end, and there are also overlapping words "desktop" and "desks".

I've tried two formulas:

```
=(LEN(JOIN(" ",A1))-LEN(SUBSTITUTE(JOIN(" ",A1),"desk","")))/LEN("desk")
```

Unfortunately this formula counts absolutely all occurrences of "desk", including overlaps in "desktop" and "desks".

```
=COUNTIF(SPLIT(JOIN(" ", A1), " -."&CHAR(10)), "desk")
```

This formula is able to count individual words, but it seems it cannot count words with some punctuation marks at the end - the number of words is always less than it actually is.

Comment: share a copy of your sheet

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try:

```
=LEN(REGEXREPLACE(REGEXREPLACE(A1, "\bdesk\b", "♦"), "[^♦]", ))
```

[image]

or:

```
=INDEX(QUERY(FLATTEN(SPLIT(REGEXREPLACE(A1, "[""\.,?!:]", ), " ")), 
 "select count(Col1) where Col1 = 'desk'"), 2)
```

[image]

Comment: Works! Thank you very much!

Answer (score 1):

If add a new column with a if condition and sum it up thereafter is ok for you, this should be enough.

REGEX pattern: "\bdesk\b"

- \b: boundary word

So it matches only the word "desk".

My table ranged from A2 to B8

```
| data             | \bdesk\b                               | result |
|------------------|----------------------------------------|--------|
| desk,            | =IF(REGEXMATCH($A3, "\bdesk\b"), 1, 0) | 1      |
| desks            | =IF(REGEXMATCH($A4, "\bdesk\b"), 1, 0) | 0      |
| xasxa desk sdasd | =IF(REGEXMATCH($A5, "\bdesk\b"), 1, 0) | 1      |
| asdasdsa desk    | =IF(REGEXMATCH($A6, "\bdesk\b"), 1, 0) | 1      |
| desktop          | =IF(REGEXMATCH($A7, "\bdesk\b"), 1, 0) | 0      |
| desk             | =IF(REGEXMATCH($A8, "\bdesk\b"), 1, 0) | 1      |
|                  | =SUM(B3:B8)                            | 4      |
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this formula. I tried this on my end and it is counting the word 'desk' in a cell correctly.

```
=(LEN(cell)-LEN(SUBSTITUTE(cell,"desk","")))/LEN("desk")
```

Comment: Thanks for a prompt reply! Unfortunately it counts also all matches in "desks" and "desktops"